# Is it possible to access provider-specific data of logged-in users in Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase

If a user logs into my Firebase store with Google authentication, the client gets access to all sorts of useful user-specific information, like the user's name and email. I might want to put this information in the store, and the client can certainly send it along in a write request. But as far as I know, there's no way to validate (on the server side) that this information is correct. There is nothing stopping someone from using a second client to send fictitious metadata.

(For instance, take a look at the skeletal [`auth` variable](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/auth.html) which is accessible from security rules. It doesn't contain the information I need for validation.)

How do people deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Only limited information about the user is available in the `auth` variable in security rules.

To access more information, you'll have to store that information in the database when the user is created or signs in. Most developers add a `/users` node to their database for this reason.

You can then look the extra information up in your security rules with something like `root.child('users').child(auth.uid)...`

The process is covered in the [Firebase documentation section on Storing User Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

Comment: But doesn't that mean that a user can can submit totally fictitious information, as long as the stuff contained in `auth` matches? So, for instance, a user logging in with a Google account could include someone else's email as their own, causing the other user to receive messages inappropriately.

This seems like a problem to me!